# What is the correct way to spawn a model to Gazebo using a Python script?

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm kinda fuzzy on this part. Here's my attempt:

```
rospy.wait_for_service("/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model")

try:
    spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy("/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model", SpawnModel)
    spawner(rover_name, str(open("/home/anh/catkin_ws/src/rover_project/rover_description/urdf/rover.urdf",'r')), "/rover", Pose(position= Point(0,0,2),orientation=Quaternion(0,0,0,0)),"world")

except rospy.ServiceException as e:
    print("Service call failed: ",e)
```

However, it leads to this result:

```
('Service call failed: ', ServiceException('service [/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model] responded with an error: ',))
```

Now, I'm pretty sure I didn't pass the urdf file the correct way. So if you guys can give me a full example on how to do it in Python, that would be awesome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337065/what-is-the-correct-way-to-spawn-a-model-to-gazebo-using-a-python-script?/) by [vitsensei](https://answers.ros.org/users/48858/vitsensei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright guys, I figured it out.

```
spawner(rover_name, str(open("/home/anh/catkin_ws/src/rover_project/rover_description/urdf/rover.urdf",'r')), "/rover", Pose(position= Point(0,0,2),orientation=Quaternion(0,0,0,0)),"world")
```

should be

```
spawner(rover_name, open("/home/anh/catkin_ws/src/rover_project/rover_description/urdf/rover.urdf",'r').read(), "/rover", Pose(position= Point(0,0,2),orientation=Quaternion(0,0,0,0)),"world")
```

instead!

---

Originally posted by [vitsensei](https://answers.ros.org/users/48858/vitsensei/) with karma: 96 on 2019-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) on 2020-01-03**:
Hey can you please share the entire code of this file. I am kind of stuck in the same problem. It would be a great help !!

**Comment by [ljburtz](https://answers.ros.org/users/37226/ljburtz/) on 2020-08-16**:
Thanks! didn't work without the open( ).read() !
Full code:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SpawnModel
spawn_model_client = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model', SpawnModel)
spawn_model_client(
    model_name='ground_plane',
    model_xml=open('/usr/share/gazebo-9/models/ground_plane/model.sdf', 'r').read(),
    robot_namespace='/foo',
    initial_pose=Pose(),
    reference_frame='world'
)
```

**Comment by [mfe7](https://answers.ros.org/users/32690/mfe7/) on 2022-01-24**:
Slightly modified this answer to include imports to make this executable as is:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SpawnModel
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
spawn_model_client = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model', SpawnModel)
spawn_model_client(
    model_name='ground_plane',
    model_xml=open('/usr/share/gazebo-9/models/ground_plane/model.sdf', 'r').read(),
    robot_namespace='/foo',
    initial_pose=Pose(),
    reference_frame='world'
)
```

**Comment by [Sindorim_Bear](https://answers.ros.org/users/95105/sindorim_bear/) on 2022-02-03**:
Hello everyone the code everyone shared seems to work well, but I found a problem I couldn't solve. After launching the model with the codes above, I searched for the model's odometry and geometry by typing rostopic list but I couldn't find anything and whenever I manually press on the model in the gazebo simulation, the program crashes. Has anyone solved this problem?

**Comment by [fegonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/67666/fegonzalez/) on 2022-05-16**:
A node should be added to work properly.

Another modification:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SpawnModel
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
rospy.init_node('insert_object',log_level=rospy.INFO)
spawn_model_client = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model', SpawnModel)
spawn_model_client(
model_name='ground_plane',
    model_xml=open('/usr/share/gazebo-9/models/ground_plane/model.sdf', 'r').read(),
    robot_namespace='/foo',
    initial_pose=Pose(),
    reference_frame='world'
)
```